# Path connectedness of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I know about Connectedness and Path Connectedness in Topology. Recently, I got stuck into a problem. Let $A$ be the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^2:$
$$A=\{(x,y) \mid (x+1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}\cup \{(x,y) \mid y=x\sin(\frac{1} {x}),\ x>0\}$$ The connectedness is obvious from if $A$ is connected then $cl(A)$ is also connected. But I can't prove the path connectedness ( The answer is given that $A$ is both connected & Path connected). Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the second set. It should be clear that $B$ is path connected.

Since $A$ is convex, it is path connected.

Let $p(x) = \begin{cases} (x,x \sin { 1\over x}) , & x \in (0,1]\\
(0,0), & x = 0 \end{cases}$.

Note that $p$ is continuous, $p(0) \in A$ and $p(1) \in B$.

Hence any two points of $A\cup B$ can be connected by a path.

Comment: I have understood.  But I have a question. If we choose $A=0×[0,1]$ then it is convex and $A \cup B$ is so called  Topologist's Sine curve. If we use your logic  then the Topologist's Sine curve is path connected. Where's the ambiguity?

Comment: The topologists sine curve does not converge to Zero.